# Integral of log over a square root

Tags: integration, logarithms

I am trying to solve $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log(z-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ for z real.  I would like a hint as to how to approach the integral (I took $\log(z)$ out and tried a trigonometric/hyperbolic substitution, but things don't seem to get nicer).

**Update:** From Gradshteyn one can find what the answer looks like for $0\leq 1\leq|z|$, namely $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log(z-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\pi\log\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2-1}}{2}$$, but the references therein don't contain information on how to evaluate it.

For z complex (which I want to compute in the end) the answer should be

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log|z-x|}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\pi\log\frac{|z+\sqrt{z^2-1|}}{2}$$

which I have no idea how to attack, hence I thought of dealing with the real case first

Comment: Just curious, but how exactly did you "take out" log z (presumably out of the integral)?

Comment: The indefinite integral is not so pretty: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+log(a-x)%2Fsqrt(1-x%5E2)

Comment: @Deepak Take z in front of bracket and split the log in $\log(z)+\log(1-x/z)$ and in the first term substitute $x=\sin(u)$ to evaluate it

Comment: This integral isn't too bad (i assume $z\geq 1$ here so the logarithm is well defined everywhere):

First, differentiate w.r.t to $z$

$$
I'(z)=\int_{-1}^1 dx\frac{1}{z-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

or substituting $x=\cos(y)$ and using parity

$$
I'(z)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dy\frac{1}{z-\cos(y)}
$$

this intergral is readily solved  (for example by a standard Weierstrass substitution or the residue theorem) yielding

$$
I'(z)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}
$$

so 

$$
I(z)=\pi \log(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})+C
$$

.......

Comment: ....
To fix the constant of integration we observe that $I(1)=-\pi\log(2)$. This follows from the fact that the integral can, by trigonomteric substitution, be simply traced back to the standard integral $\int_0^{\pi}\log(\sin(x))=-\pi\log(2)$. 

$$
I(z)=\pi \log\left(\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2-1}}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: for $z<1$ the integral is not well defined, because log is negative

Comment: @tired Very nice! I was trying a similar thing but with $x=sin(u)$ which leads to nasty arctans everywhere. Did you see my update about the case of z being complex and having a modulus? I am not sure whether one can first do the z-real case with modulus signs and then say that both sides are analytic functions of z, hence we can extend to the complex plane?

Comment: The second part of my comment above is stupid, log is not analytic in the complex plane